# Angular 5 Service As singleton

Tags: angular, service, singleton

I'm working on Angular 5 singleton service. In my opinion I did everything according to guideline, unfortunately my service is NOT singleton. Each component seems to have it's on service instance.
My Code looks like this:

**App Module:**

```
import { StarService } from './star-service/star-service'
import { StarSearchComponent } from './star-search/star-search.component'
import { StarReportComponent } from './star-report/star-report.component';
@NgModule({
imports: [
BrowserModule,
   FormsModule,
   AppRoutingModule
],
declarations: [
 AppComponent,
 StarSearchComponent, 
 StarReportComponent
],
providers: [StarService
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { log } from 'util';
@Injectable()
export class StarService {
public Param: string;

constructor() { 
this.Param = "Not Set";
console.log("Service Instance created");
}
}
```

**Star Report Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StarService } from '../star-service/star-service'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-star-report',
  templateUrl: '<p>{{getReport}}</p>',
  styleUrls: ['./star-report.component.css']
})
export class StarReportComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private starService: StarService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  this.starService.Param = "Report";
}

 get getReport(): string
  {
   return this.starService.Param;
  }
 }
```

**Star Search Component**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { StarService } from '../star-service/star-service'

 @Component({
 selector: 'app-star-search',
 templateUrl: './star-search.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./star-search.component.css']
 })
 export class StarSearchComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private starService: StarService) { }
 ngOnInit() {
  }
 get getSearch(): string
 {
   return this.starService.Param;
 }
 }
```

And now, my console displays "Service Instance created" each time I'm switching component. 
Also, each component display wrong text. I belive, when StarReportComponent is create, it switches starService.Param = "Report" and it shall stay there.
Unfortunatelly, when StarSearchComponent is called, it displays default "Not Set". Why? Why singleton is not working here?
Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce this with your example code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mwxab5?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks, I see that you create both components in the same time:   <app-star-report></app-star-report>
<app-star-search></app-star-search>. I'm rather switching between them through routing. Does it makes any difference ?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

What you are asking for is a `static` property in your Service. Otherwise, it is working as expected. If you want to make a property of your service singleton throughout, declare it like this in your service,

```
export class StarService {

static _param: string;

// use getters and setters to access them from your instantiated service objects from within various components
get Param() { return StarService._param; }

set Param(param: string) { StarService._param = param; }

}
```

**EDIT**

Oh I am sorry, just re-read your question, it is behaving as expected. Since you have `this.Param = "Not Set";` in the constructor of your service, everytime you switch between your components, it forces the instantiation of this singleton service again in your component (through the constructor's argument in your component) which in turn makes the constructor of service called again and thus reverts back the `Param`'s value to `"Not Set"`. Makes sense?

**EDIT-2**

Answering to your comment, it is due to the [dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#application-wide-dependencies) of the service into the component done through its (component's) constructor.

In short, injecting the service like this,

```
constructor(private starService: StarService) { }
```

as per the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#application-wide-dependencies),

> A provider is something that can create or deliver a service. Angular creates a service instance from a class provider by using `new`.

will under the hood assign the `private starService` property to,

```
private starService = new StarService();
```

which will call the service's constructor.

If you don't want any default actions to happen every time the service is injected, then don't perform any property assignments within its (service's) constructor.

And, every time you switch between components through its routes, the corresponding component gets created by calling its constructor and the corresponding [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) it has implemented. Hence it will also create the corresponding dependencies defined within their constructors as well. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: I know how static works, but I'm asking why StarService is not injected as singleton?

Comment: Thanks. But why service constructor is called several times? Singleton is created only once, isn't it?

Comment: So every time component is switched, I get new instance of service? How this can work? https://octoperf.com/blog/2016/03/29/singleton-service-using-angular2/

Comment: this doesn't really make sense, according to the document here, the service is supposed to be created just once and share that instance to any class that asks for it to inject into https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Comment: and here also https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection "Angular module providers (@NgModule.providers) are registered with the application's root injector. Angular can inject the corresponding services in any class it creates. Once created, a service instance lives for the life of the app and Angular injects this one service instance in every class that needs it." ---> there can be an issue if your StarService is instances many times

Comment: This indeed defeats the purpose of having a service defined only in your app root

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with this problem for quite some time. I wanted to have a singleton and whenever I routed from one link to the other the service, that I expected to be singleton, was recreated. Finally the solution was to change the navigation link:

From :

`<a href="/customers">Customers</a>`

To:

`<a routerLink="/customers">Customers</a>`

I have forked the link from angular documentation on singleton to remove the usage of commonmodule and sharedmodule to prove that this isn't causing the problem. Although I do agree that using commonmodule and sharedmodule makes the modules more modular.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uxbbdx

I have lazy loading modules similar to the example. Let me know if this does not solve the issue for you. I have played around with this problem for quite some time and probably will be able to help by recreating the issue again.